# DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body embeds[0][LIST_ITEM_VALUE_REQUIRED]: List item values of ModelType are required

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried to make a role edit command using discord.js, and it will turn out as a normal result if there's nothing to edit, but it caught an error when I put something that I want to edit in the command.

I know there are other posts I can search, but I don't understand what they explained.

The code down below is the whole edit subcommand in the role command.

```js
const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();
const role = interaction.options.get('role').value;

...

else if (subcommand === 'edit') {
            const { options } = interaction;

            const name = options.get('name')?.value;
            const color = options.get('color')?.value;
            const hoist = options.get('hoist')?.value;
            const mentionable = options.get('mentionable')?.value;

            const embed = new EmbedBuilder();

            if (name !== undefined) {
                const ogName = rid.name;

                if (ogName !== name) {
                    rid.edit({ name: name }).then(async () => {
                        embed
                            .setDescription(`已編輯身分組 ${rid}`)
                            .setColor(rid.hexColor)
                            .addFields({
                                name: '名稱',
                                value: `${name}`,
                                inline: true,
                            });
                    }).catch(async err => {
                        console.error(0, err);
                    });
                } else {
                    embed
                        .setColor('Red')
                        .setDescription(`身分組 ${rid} 並未做出任何更改`);
                }
            }

            if (color !== undefined) {
                const ogColor = rid.hexColor;

                if (ogColor !== color) {
                    rid.edit({ color: color }).then(async () => {
                        embed
                            .setDescription(`已編輯身分組 ${rid}`)
                            .setColor(rid.hexColor)
                            .addFields({
                                name: '顏色',
                                value: `${color}`,
                                inline: true,
                            });
                    }).catch(async err => {
                        console.error(1, err);
                    });
                } else {
                    embed
                        .setColor('Red')
                        .setDescription(`身分組 ${rid} 並未做出任何更改`);
                }
            }

            if (hoist !== undefined) {
                const ogHoist = rid.hoist;

                if (ogHoist !== hoist) {
                    rid.edit({ hoist: hoist }).then(async () => {
                        embed
                            .setDescription(`已編輯身分組 ${rid}`)
                            .setColor(rid.hexColor)
                            .addFields({
                                name: '分開顯示',
                                value: `${hoist}`,
                                inline: true,
                            });
                    }).catch(async err => {
                        console.error(2, err);
                    });
                } else {
                    embed
                        .setColor('Red')
                        .setDescription(`身分組 ${rid} 並未做出任何更改`);
                }
            }

            if (mentionable !== undefined) {
                const ogMention = rid.mentionable;

                if (ogMention !== mentionable) {
                    rid.edit({ mentionable: mentionable }).then(async () => {
                        embed
                            .setDescription(`已編輯身分組 ${rid}`)
                            .setColor(rid.hexColor)
                            .addFields({
                                name: '是否可被提及',
                                value: `${mentionable}`,
                                inline: true,
                            });
                    }).catch(async err => {
                        console.error(3, err);
                    });
                } else {
                    embed
                        .setColor('Red')
                        .setDescription(`身分組 ${rid} 並未做出任何更改`);
                }
            }

            console.log(name, color, hoist, mentionable);

            if (name !== undefined && color !== undefined && mentionable !== undefined && hoist !== undefined) {
                embed
                    .setColor('Red')
                    .setDescription(`身分組 ${rid} 並未做出任何更改`);

                return await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
            } else {
                return await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
            }

        } else ...
```

and I executed the command `/role edit role:@role name:human` and there's the result

```js
human undefined undefined undefined
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0][LIST_ITEM_VALUE_REQUIRED]: List item values of ModelType are required
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1021:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:862:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async InteractionWebhook.editMessage (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:338:15)    
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.editReply (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:158:17)
    at async Object.callback (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\commands\roles\role.js:294:24)
    at async module.exports (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\events\interactionCreate\handleCommands.js:117:9)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\handlers\eventHandler.js:21:17) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [Array],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined,
      thread_name: undefined
    }
  },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Invalid Form Body',
    code: 50035,
    errors: { embeds: [Object] }
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/1089391898935967764/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEzODc4Mjk0NjMzODI5NTg5OTpkakNjVW1sWU1qZURWVkc3OG42cldXd2lpaTIydVYySTlqQ0Z5d3J4TEVqa090U1VWQkN3MlRmMGd1dkpLYTh6WXRPaUZXdnQ5c3NBWllnQTFCQWdnZTgwaXpwcmd4UlJuVUtoOFlpb2RKb1ZlRUU3c2hSNVo2OUNIVE9rTWR4ZA/messages/@original'
}
Error caught while running role: DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0][LIST_ITEM_VALUE_REQUIRED]: List item values of ModelType are required
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1021:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:862:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async InteractionWebhook.editMessage (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:338:15)    
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.editReply (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:158:17)
    at async Object.callback (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\commands\roles\role.js:294:24)
    at async module.exports (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\events\interactionCreate\handleCommands.js:117:9)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\Discord-v14\handlers\eventHandler.js:21:17) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [Array],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined,
      thread_name: undefined
    }
  },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Invalid Form Body',
    code: 50035,
    errors: { embeds: [Object] }
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/1089391898935967764/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEzODc4Mjk0NjMzODI5NTg5OTpkakNjVW1sWU1qZURWVkc3OG42cldXd2lpaTIydVYySTlqQ0Z5d3J4TEVqa090U1VWQkN3MlRmMGd1dkpLYTh6WXRPaUZXdnQ5c3NBWllnQTFCQWdnZTgwaXpwcmd4UlJuVUtoOFlpb2RKb1ZlRUU3c2hSNVo2OUNIVE9rTWR4ZA/messages/@original'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right way to get options? You could be specific for each option as `.getRole()`, `.getString()`, etc. [CommandInteractionOptionResolver](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the value, not just `.get()`.

For example:

```js
options.getString('text') // String
options.getNumber('how-many-people') // Number
```